# Show exposed filter by logged in user in drupal 8

Tags: views, 8, forms

I have a view that in that view I set up 3 exposed filter, all filtering working fine.

- First: Filter by contact first name
- Second: Filter by Project name
- Third: Filter by Contact region/location

The third filter should be shown just for specific logged in user, and that user should be Administrator.

I tried the following codes and it does not working, even doesn't show the Var_dump, so how should it change to work?

```
function my_modulename_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {

    //unset($form['average']);

    var_dump($form);

    die();
  }
}
```

> Here I attached my view configuration and settings may help you to get what I have in my view

[image]

Comment: May you provide the exact code you are using? Showing a `if` statement and saying  _it does not change anything_ is quite broad. I doubt that is the real code you are using; if that is the code you wrote so far, then the question is really broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following example unsets the filter `average` when user is NOT administrator, you can modify it to your specific case.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
function my_modulename_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){

  $roles = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
  $is_user_admin = in_array("administrator", $roles);
  $is_exposed = $form_id == 'views_exposed_form';
  $is_filter_set = isset($form['average']);

  if ( $is_exposed && $is_filter_set && !$is_user_admin ) {
    unset($form['average']);
  }
}
```

If you want to unset only on a specific view exposed form use this condition

```
$is_our_view = $form["#id"] == "views-exposed-form-article-page-1";
```

Comment: unset($form['average']); not working for me and I use the `$form['field_regions_target_id']['#access']=false;` in my case, thanks.

Comment: I thought your filter id was `average` (from your question), try `unset($form['field_regions_target_id'])`